# Trying to get Dreamweaver to find and delete tracking code on a link using regex

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I'm trying to find the Dreamweaver search/replace regex for removing tracking code from an a tag by matching everything between `?elqTrackId` and the quotation mark closing the href, and deleting that whole thing. Any suggestions?

I would think finding `\?elqTrackId(.*)\"` and replacing it with `\"` would do the trick, but it doesn't. Just finding what's between the question mark and the closing quote should also work.

Comment: What constitutes "but it doesn't."?

Comment: Can you add an example of the block of text you're working with, then show us the portion you want to select?